# Adding a domain to a django webapp running on digital ocean

Tags: django, dns, django-subdomains

I have a Django Web App that is currently live on digital ocean with an IP address say w.x.y.z, I have also bought a domain name say example.com, how can i add this to my app so that, when i go to example.com , I get to my website which currently is only accessible through the IP. Any advice is appreciated. I'm new to this

Comment: THis is not a setting in Django, you will need to edit the DNS record of the domain you have bought. For example a manual for hover: https://help.hover.com/hc/en-us/articles/217282457-How-to-Edit-DNS-records-A-AAAA-CNAME-MX-TXT-SRV-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Buy/Register your Domain Name with Domain Name providers.
2. You need to mention your IP in your DNS Management side at Domain Name service providers.

At Django Side - you just make sure to add your Domain Name into `settings.py` file, in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

And you are done!

Comment: do you know if I have to edit something in the nginx settings?

Comment: Yes.  So digital ocean serves Django via Ngnix :)
check the documentation at - https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Here also - you need to tell Ngnix what Domain Name you are service via what IP.

Comment: Before everything - check Digital ocean, they must have documented procedure to handle this case.  You may need to skip modification of `settings.py`.